# Springboot adds slash after host in url and then reject request because of double slash

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, slash

I am developing springboot application with rest api.
Recently I added simple spring security using jwt. 
On localhost everything works fine, but when uploaded on server its not working.
Locally with our without security and online without security everything works, but online with security
the url is somehow changed and even when I use request with Postman (www.server.com/api/plants) response is like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-11T11:52:58.063+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String \"//\"",
    "path": "//api/plants/"
}
```

Something is adding another slash before api. 
How can I get rid of second slash or make Springboot accept address?

```
2020-06-11 13:52:58.060 ERROR 24465 --- [nio-8097-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//"
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception{

web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
    web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
}
@Bean
public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
    return firewall;
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register").permitAll().
                    anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

WebConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("**")
                    .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code.

Comment: What are you hosting on? (like any other path forwarder e.g. apache, cloud front messing up with your resource and redirecting `/api` to `//api`)

Comment: Thanks @YoManTaMero . Indeed it was redirecting issue.